# Project management tool (iOS)

Tags: ios, project-management, productivity

I'm a user of OmniFocus, but I'm using an outdated version b/c I'm too annoyed to buy the update for another $40.

I could use a recommendation for a project management tool that can do the following:

- Allows tasks and sub tasks "within tasks" (therefore "Things" is out)
- Some kind of iphone/ipad/Apple Watch integration
- Possible to email tasks to the system
- No need for collaboration or time-tracking
- No problem to pay for it of course, but I don't want to pay a monthly subscription.

I wouldn't think it would be that difficult, but most apps I found are either "Flat" to do lists with no sub-lists possible or else extremely complex programs meant for collaboration with large teams.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want something lightweight that lets you do deeply nested structures (like sub-sub-sub-subtasks), you might want to take a look at [WorkFlowy](http://workflowy.com). It is web-based to mobile use should work.
While it is not primarily a task management tool, it does support marking items as done.